# onERC721Received doesn't revert?

Tags: erc-721

I'm trying to get my `onERC721Received` function to revert with a super obvious `require` statement failure but it seems to go through and transfer the ERC721.

I've tried other things like comparing the `operator` or `from` address to `msg.sender` and trying both `!=` and `==` just to try to get it to revert and nothing seems to work.

```
contract Reject is IERC721Receiver { 

    function onERC721Received(address operator, address from, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory) public override returns(bytes4) {
        require(true == false, "true not false, duh");

        return bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"));
    }

}
```

This function should definitely be able to revert, right?

Comment: I am observing this same behavior

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error with the following code in remix.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

contract Reject is IERC721Receiver { 

    function onERC721Received(address operator, address from, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory) public override returns(bytes4) {
        require(true == false, "true not false, duh");

        return bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"));
    }

}
```

However, it was not possible. The transaction is reverted with the following reason: "true not false, duh". For me the code works as expected...